# Simulate SNMP traps to test surveillance

Tags: oid, snmp, surveillance

I'm trying to use Net-SNMP on Windows to emulate a trap that should trigger an alarm on our surveillance system.

This is the setup:

- Windows 7 client that sends the trap
- Net-SNMP as software for sending the trap
- Linux with Adventnet ManageEngine OpManager as NMS (not relevant)

This is what I'm trying to accomplish

send trap with OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 (according to the MIB I have loaded into my NMS) and just some sort of message into it to see if I can get any alarm in my NMS. I can see that I actually send a trap in my firewall, but I have no idea what it contains.

This is my attempt so far:

`snmptrap.exe -v 2c -c xxxxxxx 192.168.100.65 '' 6 0 .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 s "123456"`

However, I can't seem to find any reasonable documentation with examples for snmptrap. Basically, I need to know what:

- '' <- why do I need this? I can omit it and it will still send a trap
- 6 <- Enterprise gneric trap, I assume. Is this correct?
- 0 <- I have no idea, I need some sort of value for this
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 <- the enterprise specific OID I assume, should this be followed by some more numbers
- s <- indicates string
- "123456" <- just a random test-string...

This doesn't make much sense to me, and if anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
snmptrap.exe -v 2c -c xxxxxxx 192.168.100.65 
'' .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.2.0.999 s "123456"
```

- '' <- the first parameter for v2c
  trap is the agent uptime,
  it is mandatory and empty parameter
  will be replaced with current value
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 <- trap OID
- .1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.2.0.999 <- varbind 
  (this needs to be defined as a string
  value in MIB)
- s <- indicates string
- "123456" <- just a random test-string...

This generates a SNMPv2c trap with the following content (as seen in wireshark):

```
      variable-bindings: 3 items
            1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0: 878104
            1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0: 1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.5089.1.0.1)
            1.3.6.1.4.1.5089.2.0.999: 31323334353 (this is 123456 octet string)
```

This output comes from snmptrap on Linux, but it seems to be the same as on Windows.

Comment: There must be something that differs in the windows version, because that exact command gives me: s: Missing type/value for variable

Comment: Okay, I figured it out that the windows version doesn't support the '' notation for "current uptime", but seems to demand a value.

Comment: Works fine also on Debian Linux. I've got an old Asterisk box which sometimes gets overloaded and needed to send appropriate strings to my snmptrap server.

Answer (score 2):

Man forget the Net- SNMP there is to much hassle using it ... just download MIB browser from http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml ... load up a mib file and u could see and send all SNMP traps.

Comment: After struggling with low-level tools, I finally managed to generate a SNMP trap that I could catch in `wbemtest`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

i also dont understand it fully, but this works for me (trial and error method ;)

snmptrap -v 2c -Ci -u user -c community  host '' .x.y.z.q.oid 1 s string 2 s string2

Comment: Without explanation of what 1 and 2 is in that example, it doesn't make any sense at all to me...? And with your example, I get this reply: s:  ("1") and no trap is sent over the network.

Comment: 1 and 2 are the first and second value in a trap. This works with linux net-snmp's snmptrapd as receiver. If you got a reply, who sent it if nothing is sent over a network? ;)